# Joomla: Plugins that modify Categories

Tags: plugins, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I am trying to make a plugin for Joomla that mimics all the changes you do on content categories in a menu item. So adding, deleting and editing the name of a category in a specific article will also make the same changes on a menu item.

A content plugin has events such as `onBeforeContentSave` and `onAfterDisplayContent` that allow you to process that data. How do I do the same thing for categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't an `onCategorySave` event. The best approach I can think of would be to create a `system` plugin and check the `task` and `option` request variables for values of `save` and `com_categories`. Your plugin would look something like this:

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');


class plgSystemCategorysave extends JPlugin
{
    function onAfterInitialise()
    {
        if (!JFactory::getApplication()->isAdmin()) {
                return; // Dont run in frontend
        }

        $option = JRequest::getCmd('option', '');
        $task = JRequest::getCmd('task', '');

        if ($option == 'com_categories' && $task == 'save') {
            // your processing code here
        }
    }
}
```